# Inspite of failing or Inspite of being failed

Tags: verbs

Which one of the followings is correct?

> i) Inspite of **failing** in her examination, Anita was not upset.
>
> ii) Inspite of **being failed** in her examination, Anita was not upset.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences don't sound natural at all. I think it's better to say it like this:

> Despite the fact that she had failed her exam, Anita was not upset.

Or if you insist on beginning your sentence with *in spite of* (notice, *in* and *spite* are written separately), rewrite it like this:

> In spite of the fact that she had failed her exam, Anita was not upset.

*despite* and *in spite of* do really mean the same thing.

Comment: I've been instructed to start with Inspite of.

Comment: @ShoaibAshraf: "Inspite of", or "In spite of"? If someone instructed you to use the former, they are completely wrong.