# Following vs followings

Tags: word-usage

> 1.Select one of the options from the *following*.
>
> 2.Select one of the options from the *followings*.

I thought till now that sentence 1 is right and 2 is not used. But I have seen a recent [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116175/inspite-of-failing-or-inspite-of-being-failed) with *followings* in it. The reviewer didn't change the word.

- which one of the above is right?
- Are both the words used?
- Does it vary in British and American english?

Comment: We don't usually correct grammatical mistakes in questions. The main reason for this is that it helps people to know when they should use simple English in their answer. You should not use questions on this site as a source of accurate or idiomatic English.

Answer (score 9):

I looked up the dictionary, Merriam Unabridged, and it is the **following**.

> — the following
>
> :  **the following one or ones — used to introduce a list, a quotation, etc.**
>
> <**The following** are some other symptoms of the condition: excessive sweating, fever, muscle aches … — Fred Cicetti, The Montague (Massachusetts) Reporter, 15 Oct. 2009>
>
> < … the question schools must ask is the following: “Are our schools places where children can thrive not just intellectually, but also emotionally and spiritually?” — Patrick F. Bassett, Independent School, Fall 2005>

And it is not an adjective, but rather **a pronoun,** which interested me also. And please be careful even if it lacks s at the end, it always should be counted as plural ( when it refers to multiple types of items ) .

And because the dictionary dictates so, wouldn't there be neither British nor American's way?

[image]

Comment: That's a good answer, though I should point out that dictionaries don't "dictate" anything in English; they just document what is used in practice. There is no official, correct, definite *anything* in English, just some elements of consensus visible in practice.

Comment: @SamBC Thanks. My answer is a kind of a reaction to that of stangton. ( He said it is an adjective, and I thought it was strange. ). Yes, dictionaries are not everything, but since I am not a native speaker, please kindly make your own answer, too.

Comment: (Also, whether it's a pronoun or a noun depends on what dictionary or other reference you look at - which does help demonstrate how much interpretation there is in English grammar.)

Comment: There's no need for me to give an extra answer when there's one that I would be adding so little in comparison to. So I just comment to point out the differences or corrections.

Comment: @SamBC Thanks for additional info. Let'ts talk about more if the word service is singular or plural. Tormenting, isn't it? :) Anyway I appreciate your service. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's always *following* in this context because it's an adjective, and we don't decline adjectives in English.  The sentence implies, because you have to choose an option, that you have to "choose from one of the following **options**", but we usually leave out the noun when it would be repetitive or clear from context.

Another way that you can tell that the word is an adjective is that *following*, the noun, doesn't describe an *option*; those things that you have to choose from are not called "followings".  Therefore it must be an adjective, which doesn't get pluralized.

Comment: I don't mind if you downvote my answers, but I would prefer if you'd leave an explanation of why you downvoted it; it might help me improve.

Comment: I would not downvote, but it is not an adjective. Merriam says, 1
:  next after :  succeeding, ensuing
<the meeting was held on the following day>
2
:  that immediately follows
<the following table shows the rate of increase>
<trains will leave at the following times>
3
of a wind :  blowing in or running in the direction in which a ship is moving
4
:  being east of or having a greater right ascension than another celestial body so as to follow it in the field of a telescope by reason of diurnal motion — compare preceding

Comment: Well, it is an adjective, but not in this case. It can be an adjective. "The following section describes etc. etc.". However, when used in this way it is a noun or pronoun, depending on who you ask. If it were an adjective here, what noun would it be modifying?

Comment: If "following" is thought of as an adjective here, it modifies an implied but omitted noun such as "options" or "list".

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to list it is ok to use the followings. In the sense of say, during your talk you are to cover the followings:
a. chicken;
b. hens;
c. rooster; and
d. birds

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].